# How to add custom parameter to Prestashop Product Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am in requirement to add custom parameters in the Product MySQL Table of Prestashop.
But I do not know where to add the lines. I have already altered the MySQL `ps_product` table, but unable to find where to write the parameter and its value in PHP file.

I was looking at the prestashop code, and stuck at line `$this->object->add()`
Now I do not know where to go further.

Can anyone please guide me where is this function or what is the any other method to pass my parameters values.

Comment: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/SQL+Manager

Comment: I am asking on which php file shall I write the code, not in SQL